# jQuery append autoincrement

Tags: jquery, html

I have a variable list of inputs, with each item having a unique incrementing name, like so...

```
<input type="text" name="values[0]" value="some text">
<input type="text" name="values[1]" value="some other text">
<input type="text" name="values[2]" value="some more text">
...
<input type="text" name="values[n]" value="last text">
```

The whole page (including the values, which are essentially an array) is produced by a PHP script, but I want to have a button to dynamically add another textbox. Quite easily possible with jQuery's append(), but I can't figure out how to get the name of the appended input to be "values[n+1]".  Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I want to have a button to dynamically add another textbox. Quite easily possible with jQuery's append(), but I can't figure out how to get the name of the appended input to be "values[n+1]"

This is one way to do this:

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var lastname = $('#inputs [name^=value]:last-child')[0].name;
  var next = parseInt(lastname.match(/\d+/)[0]) + 1;
  $('#inputs').append('<input type="text" name="values[' + next + ']" value="more more text">');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputs">
<input type="text" name="values[0]" value="some text">
<input type="text" name="values[1]" value="some other text">
<input type="text" name="values[2]" value="some more text">
</div>
<button id="btn">Append</button>
```

Comment: Perfect - this is exactly what I was looking for, I'm just not familiar enough with jQuery's syntax yet for it to be obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PHP for your backend, you can name them `values[]` and PHP will automatically bundle them for you into an array.

This saves having to muck around with any JavaScript.

If you really wanted to use jQuery to do it, you could try run this on all your inputs...

```
$('input').attr('name', function(index) { return 'values[' + index + ']'; });
```

Which will re-index all of them based on their index.

Comment: **Important note:** `$('input').attr('name', function(index) { return 'values[' + index + ']'; });` will compromise (other) current document names

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It was expected you would change the selector to suit those inputs.

Comment: Great comment. I would expect that too.